# make localmodconfig does not update .config file

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to compile a stripped down distro kernel. I am using FEDORA and it has about 4000 odd configuration options. I am just trying to install a plain kernel, so I was looking a way to do this. I came across the target "make localmodconfig" which claims that it automatically checks what modules have been loaded in the system and disables everything else.

I wanted to make use of this and hence copied the distro kernel's config file , placed it in my source tree and ran make localmodconfig. **However the script seems to still ask Y/N/M for all the options**. I expected it would produce a .config file with only necessary options enabled. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the *oldconfig* make target, after disabling all unneeded drivers, the program will ask for any options that aren't yet set.

If you don't want to waste time with that, you can press the enter key to accept each question's suggested answer – in most cases, these settings are appropriate. To further modify the parameters set by *localmodconfig* in the configuration file, launch one of the regular configuration programs after your make call – for instance via the *menuconfig* or *xconfig* make targets.